# Clone mysql database replacing some fields with predefined or default values

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to copy MySQL database while replacing some vulnerable data(e/g. email, phone, name, etc/) How can I efficiently achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps

- dump your database
- import your database
- obfuscate values in your copy
- remove your old dump
- dump your second database
- do whatever you need with the dump of the copy